# How to write a template which accepts variadic list of types and integers

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a template that accepts a variadic "list of pairs".  The "pairs" would be a type then a size.

I have written something that works:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N>
class DeferPair
{
    using Type = T;
    static constexpr size_t kSize = N;

public:
    void defer(const T& e)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        //Defer this specific type into a fixed-length/statically-allocated queue
        //Discard oldest if the queue is already full
    }
};

template <typename... Pairs>
class Defer;

template <typename Pair, typename... RemainingPairs>
class Defer<Pair, RemainingPairs...> : public Pair, public Defer<RemainingPairs...>
{
public:
    using Pair::defer;
    using Defer<RemainingPairs...>::defer;
};

template <typename Pair>
class Defer<Pair> : public Pair
{
public:
    using Pair::defer; 
};

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

int main()
{
    Defer<DeferPair<A, 1>, DeferPair<B, 2>, DeferPair<C, 3>> d;

    d.defer(A{});
    d.defer(B{});
    d.defer(C{});

    return 0;
}
```

But I would really like the syntax for usage to be simpler.
Instead of:

```
Defer<DeferPair<A, 1>, DeferPair<B, 2>, DeferPair<C, 3>> d;
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Defer<A, 1, B, 2, C, 3> d;
```

Is this possible to accomplish? (Perhaps I should also ask, is that truly more readable and is there a better option?)

Comment: Mixing type and non type template parameters in a variadic context is not a supported feature.

Comment: `Defer<A,X<1>,B,X<2>>`  is easy to get, but `Defer<A,1,B,2,C,3>` not

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai So that would be an example of using a "value type?"  Which I suppose might be a little simpler syntax (I could call X, "Size").

Comment: Maybe `std::integral_constant`? You can give it an alias.

Comment: is there a direct mapping from `A` to `1` ? Or are any combinations possible? Eg `DeferPair<A,42>` as well as `DeferPair<A,1000>` etc

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Any combination is allowed.  My eventual intent is to generate a statically-allocated (think memory pool) of the types with a given size.  Thus, the user can choose a any size for a any type.

Comment: From a naming standpoint, I think I might just go with "Defer" instead of "DeferPair", and "Defers" instead of "Defer".  That way "Defer" represents a single one while "Defers" (plural) is a set of multiple "Defer."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *"old"* way would be (up to a hard coded value):

```
// void used as not provided, you might use specific type instead
template <typename T0, size_t N0,
          typename T1 = void, size_t N1 = 0,
          ..,
          typename TN = void, size_t NN = 0>
// using Defer = DeferImpl<DeferPair<T0, N0>,
//                         DeferPair<T1, N1>, .., 
//                         DeferPair<TN, NN>>;
class Defer
{
    // ...
};
```

And unfortunately, there are no equivalent variadic way to mix types and values as variadic template argument list.